# Flutter BLoC implementation with streamBuilder

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, bloc

I have a problem with my BLoC implementation, I have this code in synchronize.dart:

```
...
class _SynchronizeState extends State<Synchronize> {
  UserBloc userBloc;
  //final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    userBloc = BlocProvider.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: Container(
        ...
        ),
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: dbRef.child('info_tekax').limitToLast(10).onValue,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError){
              Map data = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
              List keys = [];
              data.forEach( (index, data) => keys.add(index) );
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => SynchronizeItem(title: keys[index], bottom: 10, onPressed: (){ print(keys[index]); })
              );
            }else{
              return Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Loading...'),
                ),
              );
            }

          }
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The previos code, works correctly, but i want implemente bloc Pattern, i have userBloc then i want to put this 
`userBloc.getDevicesForSinchronized()` 
instead of 
`dbRef.child('info_tekax').limitToLast(10).onValue,`

my problem is this:

```
void getDevicesForSynchronized() {
  return dbRef.child(DEVICES).limitToLast(10).onValue;
}
```

i get this error **A vaue of type 'Stream' can't be returned from method 'getDevicesForSynchronized' because it has a return type of 'void'

The error is very clear, but i don't know what is type that i need return, try:

```
Furure<void> getDevicesForSynchronized() async {
  return await dbRef.child(DEVICES).limitToLast(10).onValue;    
}
```

or

```
Furure<void> getDevicesForSynchronized() async {
  dynamic result = await dbRef.child(DEVICES).limitToLast(10).onValue;    
}
```

and another solutions, but I don't know how return correctly value for use in the StreamBuilder

Answer (score 0):

From the error message you can see that the return type is Stream. Change your method like:

```
Future<Stream> getDevicesForSynchronized() async {
  return dbRef.child(DEVICES).limitToLast(10).onValue;    
}
```

Comment: i get, await applied to 'Stream<Event>' which is not a Future T_T

Comment: @UzielTrujillo: On which line you are getting that error ?

Comment: @Mihum MP, in my declaration method